# Most efficient way to convert word containing many Mathtype equations to LyX

Tags: equations, lyx, msword

I use LyXConverter from 
http://www.editorium.com/lyxconverter.htm

It does not convert equations, which are displayed as "no file found", that is, empty files, in LyX. so I have to use "toggle tex" function in Mathtype for each single Mathtype equation and paste it into the converted LyX version.

I also want to preserve the cross-reference of author-year style by using Endnote, as well as cross reference of equation numbers of Mathtype.

My deadline is coming soon, so is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Maybe: [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) to LaTeX, then LaTeX into LyX?

Comment: I also want to preserve the cross-reference of  author-year style by using Endnote, as well as cross reference of equation numbers of Mathtype. Does your suggestion works well for my purpose?

Comment: I recently had to convert a 150+ pages Word document into LaTeX and used OpenOffice with the LaTeX-export-plugin.  It worked quite well, although it needed quite a bit of cleaning the code, due to the lack of not being able to precise manipulate the content in Word.  (E.g. I had a lot of stupid things like `\textit{\textbf{\texit{}}}` or `foo\textbf{\ }bar`.)  Besides that, it worked well.  Unfortunately, I can tell, if math formulae would be also transformed correct, as my document doesn't contain real math.  It contained some exponents, which where converted properly.

Answer (score 1):

Update for those who are seeking solutions: Now I am using a commercial software converting word to latex, and importing latex code into LyX by choosing "file"-> "import"->"latex plain" command in LyX. Although there are some new issues (see my other questions) compared to manually doing for each equation, overall, I think this is still more efficient.

Comment: Could you state the name of the software you used?